# Retrieve actual Table schema (excluding addtional table schema)In vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ado.net, oledb

When I am running this code its also retrieving some other fields which are not present in a table. How to overcome this?

```
Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection 'Create a connection string for an Access database Dim strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\check\a.mdb" 'Attach the connection string to the connection object conn.ConnectionString = strConnectionString 'Open the connection conn.Open() Dim Restrictions() As String = {Nothing, Nothing, selected, Nothing} 'selected contains the name of table 
 Dim CollectionName As String = "Columns" Dim dt As DataTable = conn.GetSchema(CollectionName, Restrictions) For Each TableRow As DataRow In dt.Rows ComboBox1.Items.Add(TableRow.Item("COLUMN_NAME"))
```

The additional schema which is also retrieved are.

1. ID
2. Date create
3. Date update
4. Id
5. Lv
6. Name
7. parent Id
8. Type
9. GUID
10. Id

And are 6 more columns, original schema is of only 5 columns

Comment: my problem is not solved yet and nobody gives the solution for it thats why i ask this

Comment: If you are not receiving satisfactory answers for an existing question you should edit that question to improve it rather than simply asking the same question again.